# Unable to install typescript on windows 10

Tags: typescript

i am try to install typescript through CMD in Windows. But i am getting these errors:

```
npm ERR! pna.nextTick is not a function
npm ERR! asyncWrite is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\deepu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-10T11_17_39_169Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm
n 10.9.0
node -v
npm -v
```

Comment: i didnt get you